# File.Copy() copying corrupt file in multithreaded C# program

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two threads in my program. ***One thread*** is keep observing the USB events (USB insterted or Removed).

***Second thread*** (file copying thread)  keep monitoring a USB insertion flag set by the first thread. As soon as, an USB is inserted, the file copying thread starts copying the Pdf files from PC to the USB.

As soon as, the USB is removed, the USB monitoring thread set the `isUSBInsterted` flag to `False` and the file copying thread is supposed to stop the file transfer.

**PROBLEM:** The problem comes only when the file copying thread is already transferring a Pdf file but the USB is already ejected. In this case, a corrupt Pdf file is created in the USB and later on even if I try to delete this file, file appears again (with other problem like cannot be overwritten etc.)

**QUESTION:** How can I make sure that `File.Copy()` do not create a corrupt file in the USB. I think that even if the program is not multi-threaded, the problem will appear because this is related to start copying the file to USB and USB is ejected at that very moment when the copying process is in progress.

**My Copying Code:**

```
    private bool CopyFile(string FilenameToBeCopied, string SrcDirectory, string DstDirectory)
    {
        bool CopiedSuccessfully = false;
        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(DstDirectory); //This will create a directory if it does not exist yet.
            File.Copy(SrcDirectory + "/" + FilenameToBeCopied, DstDirectory + "/" + FilenameToBeCopied, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Copied: " + FilenameToBeCopied);
            CopiedSuccessfully = true;
        }
        catch (IOException copyError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
        }
        return CopiedSuccessfully;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about this. You're not supposed to remove storage devices as they are being written to, since it can result in corrupt files (as you have discovered).

Comment: `File.Copy` won't offer you any resilience in this situation. You will likely have to resort to opening a file stream and copying across buffers while you can, and when you receive the event for an unplugged device, remember where you got to in the file stream and close it down. This will leave a partial file, but one you can resume when the device gets inserted again.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Even if you are writing a single buffer at a time, if you eject the device partway through, you can end up with a corrupted file. And of course if you eject the device, the call to Stream.Write() is probably going to throw an IOException. At that point, there's no file stream to "close down".

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah you can, I don't deny that. The resilience will come in from tolerances I guess. Personally what I would do is either bin the file completely, or backtrack to a buffer you know has been written - say minus 2 seconds from when you received the event. None of that is trivial or guaranteed though - the only option is to bin any files being written on the event, or if the event is very close to the last file being written - consider binning it too. At the end of the copy, a hash verification could be done and any files failing could be deleted.

Comment: I think one possibility could be to check the exact size of the file to be copied `->`  copy the file into buffer `->` if the size of buffer is equal to the size of file to be copied then copy the file............does it make sense?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I think the issue is that the file on the device has been corrupted, so nothing you do at the PC end is going to help. The OP says that they can't even delete the file off the device (i.e. it's borked). Unfortunately if the hardware is in the middle of changing the flash memory and the power suddenly disappears, it's likely to get screwed up, and there's nothing anyone can do about that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oh yeah, didn't spot that. Odd, wonder if that is due to the `File.Copy`, perhaps a temporary file or something.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth It could be due to the power going off as the file tables on the memory stick are being updated, resulting in an invalid state in the file table.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Nothing should be being changed in that regard, as the file is being copied off, not moved off.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: The corrupted files can cannot be deleted even manually. And if I try to run the `File.Copy()` again on the corrputed file, I catch an exception something like `The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`

Comment: @skm Try opening a file stream and reading manually and unplugging to see if it corrupts in that situation too. You'd need to review the implementation of `File.Copy` in the .NET framework source code to see if it does something funny.

Comment: How does Windows handle these kind of events?. This is a very usual thing...people try to copy something to USB and sometimes removed the USB suddenly (improper ejection).

Comment: @skm It's not so much how Windows handles it as how the device handles it. If the device has been disconnected, there's nothing Windows can do since it is exactly that - disconnected.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth You have it the wrong way around - the file is being copied TO the device: `the file copying thread starts copying the Pdf files from PC to the USB`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: No, I mean the logic behind dealing with such cases.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ah, fair enough, sorry. Not sure you're going to get the relevant access to the file system without `PInvoke`ing something then.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an expected result**

If I understand your question, you are writing to a storage medium, and while doing this, you remove it. This is like asking for data to become corrupted.

*Edit:*

This is obviously something that is caused by users who do not know how to operate a computer, and while it will happen I wouldn't waste too much time on it. I would tackle the issue in another way, instead of trying to recover the corrupted data.

1. Give the user clear messages on what is going on, so that they can identify a copy operation is going on, and that removing the USB drive now will lead to problems.
2. Notify the user that the operation has ended and that it is safe to remove the USB drive.
3. You will be able to detect if the USB drive was removed while a copy process was running, notify the user about it, and ask them to plug it back in.
4. If Step 3 happens, check if you are able to overwrite, you never know. If it doesn't work, slightly change the filename with a suffix and write it with that filename to the USB drive. This way the user gets what he needs in any case, even if he messed up.
5. If file names matter, and a suffix is not an option you could even try to write the file with a generic UUID as filename, and rename the file back to its source-filename once the process completed successfully, this way any corrupted files won't become an issue and no suffix is needed in those cases.

If the possibility exists you might want to check if formatting the drive is an option in such cases. It will probably solve your issue and *might* be a minor issue to the user.

Comment: and thats the problem that I cannot overwrite the corrupted files. As soon as I try to overwrite the corrupted files, I catch an expection saying `The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`

Comment: @r41n If you are lucky, you can remove the existing corrupt file on the USB drive. But most likely, you will either need to run chkdsk.exe and hope it will fix the corrupt filesystem on your USB stick, or you have to re-format dhe USB stick. Bar all that, you could use NTFS instead of FAT on your USB stick, NTFS is quite a bit more resilient to corruption.

Comment: @nos: thanks, I tried to run the `CHKDSK` and it removed the corrupt files. Now, I am planning to make a logic to check the directory if there is any corrupt file in it and run the `CHKDSK` if there is one.

Comment: @nos, I know. If I were the OP, I probably would be looking for a way to get the job done, a way to get my application to deliver. Running chkdsk or formatting the drive every time the user f**ks up is probably undesirable. It also is better to prevent than to cure IMO.